# Table row height and list row height issue in Chrome when zooming in and out

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here in first image when the browser is 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0TNj.jpg)

[Here in the second image when browser is 90% or 110% or 120%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGmpt.jpg)

```css
ul{
   margin: 0px;
   }
   ul li{
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
   width: 200px;
   }
   .Left {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
   }
   tr td{
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
   }
   table thead tr th {
    display: none;
   }
   a{
    text-decoration: none;
   }
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="Left">
    <div class="title">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Name1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Name2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Name3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Name4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Name5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Name6</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <table>
      <thead>
       <th>
        <td>
         <a href="#">Status</a>
        </td>
       </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my html and css code, and screen shots also added above. this issue coming only in chrome browser in other browser no issues.I checked in other browser.

can any one help me to fix this issue. thanks.

Comment: That's because the list of names is not inside the table. The list items have different line heights and paddings than the table cells, so naturally this can cause rounding errors when zoomed: 30px * 120% zoom factor, rounded to whole pixels, is not necessarily the same as 28px * 120% + 2*1px*120%, all rounded to whole pixels.

Comment: @MrLister  i checked in other browser it is working fine, but not working in chrome browser only.

Comment: You'd better use either a table with multiple columns, either lists, but not a mixing of them. Is there anything that forces you to use a mix ?

Comment: It's already implemented in application, now it's not possible to change. any other alternative solutions please suggest me.

Comment: @MrLister Can you please suggest me the css which is suitable for all browser's

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where I only modified CSS :
(And made a little correction in the HTML, because `td` shouldn't be in a `th`)

```css
.Left, ul, li, table, tr, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
}

.Left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}

table thead {
  display: none;
}

li,
td {
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="Left">
    <div class="title">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Name1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>
            <!-- td NOT NECESSARY -->
            <a href="#">Status</a>
            <!-- /td NOT NECESSARY -->
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table so that there is no space between cells. That way, we can set the same heights for the `li` and `td` elements.

Comment: Issue is there with the above code, can please check in chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make sure the structures on the left have the same metrics as the things on the right. So no differences in padding, line-height, height etc. A bit like this:

```css
/* make sure the ul and the table have the same metrics */
.Left ul, table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* ditto for the list items and table cells */
.Left li, td {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
}

.Left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr td {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

table thead tr th {
  display: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="Left">
    <div class="title">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Header</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Name1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <td>
              <a href="#">Status</a>
          </td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Status1</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work as well as I expected though; there are still differences at some zoom factors. It could be I forgot one or more properties; when I think of some I'll update.